# In OctoberCMS, is it possible to make a type: tagList depend on a type: dropdown form field?

Tags: octobercms

In OctoberCMS you can quite easily make a dropdown list depend on another dropdown. However, I was not able find a solution to make a tagList form field depend on a dropdown.

For example, I have the following fields on a backend form:

```
-Subject
-Category
-Tags
```

I have the following tables in DB:

```
-subjects(subject_id, subject, category_id)
-categories(category_id, category)
-tags(tag_id, tag)
-categories_tags(category_id, tag_id) pivot table
-subject_tags(subject_id, tag_id) pivot table
```

I want to populate my tagList tag selector based on the category that has been selected from a dropdown on the same form. Like I select photography category and I get back the tags that are assigned with photography.

**Is it possible to do this in October?**

**What models and relations should I use to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

Of Course you can. The method I used as following.

1. Add dependsOn to the field which depend on the category in
   field.yaml file(similar as dropdowns). My fields.yaml file
   screenshot has been attached here.

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFxt0.png)
2. Then create getYOUR_FIELDOptions() method as using in normal
   taglists.
3. Create a query using below format and return it as return value of above method

   Service::whereIn('category', explode(',',$this->categories))
       ->orderBy('id')
       ->lists('title', 'id');

   - Service - Your model
   - $this->category - Depending field name
   - lists('title', 'id') - Put the field type which should display on the
     taglist in as first parameter, then the next field will be be used as
     the key. This method perfectly worked for me.

   Complete method:

   ```
       public function getServicesOptions() {

       return Service::whereIn('category', explode(',',$this->categories))->orderBy('id')->lists('title', 'id');
   }
   ```